# How to make a package of imessage extension with Xcode so that could be imported

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

We use Unity to generate a project to Xcode and want to take the advantage of the iMessage extension, But the only way to do that is making the extension after the Xcode project was generated by Unity, So every time we build our project we should set up the iMessage extension all over again.

Although we had made the iMessage extension a folder and saved on disk so that every time the Xcode project was generated we have to

1. add the iMessage extension features with Xcode.
2. drag something into the Xcode to override the generated code with the prefab ones.

And this procedure is annoying, So we are seeking of some other way which is easy to do this.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can use Unity xcode api for this
See https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/xcodeapi

Basically you create a build post-processor that creates a new target and adds the sticker resources to the new generated build.

```
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Callbacks;
using MightyEditor.iOS.Xcode;

public class BuildPostProcessor
{
    [PostProcessBuild(2000)]
    public static void OnPostProcessBuild(BuildTarget buildTarget, string buildPath)
    {
        Debug.Log("------ buildTarget:" + buildTarget + " path:" + buildPath);

        if (buildTarget == BuildTarget.iOS)
        {
            string xcodeprojPath = buildPath + "/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj";
            string pbxprojPath = xcodeprojPath + "/project.pbxproj";

            PBXProject pbxProject = new PBXProject();
            pbxProject.ReadFromFile(pbxprojPath);            

            AddStickers(pbxProject, buildPath, xcodeprojPath, pbxprojPath);

            pbxProject.WriteToFile(pbxprojPath);
        }
    }

    private static void AddStickers(PBXProject pbxProject, string buildPath,string xcodeprojPath,string pbxprojPath)
    {
        string appGuid = pbxProject.TargetGuidByName(PBXProject.GetUnityTargetName());
        DirectoryCopy("_Stickers", buildPath + "/Stickers", true);

        string stickersGuid = pbxProject.AddAppExtension(appGuid, "stickers app", "com.apple.product-type.app-extension.messages-sticker-pack", "Stickers/Info.plist");

        pbxProject.AddFile("Stickers/Stickers.xcassets", "Stickers/Stickers.xcassets");
        pbxProject.AddFileToResourcesForTarget(stickersGuid, "Stickers/Stickers.xcassets");

        pbxProject.AddBuildProperty(stickersGuid, "PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER", "com.blABLA");
        pbxProject.AddBuildProperty(stickersGuid, "TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY", "1,2");
        pbxProject.AddBuildProperty(stickersGuid, "ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME", "iMessage App Icon");
        pbxProject.AddBuildProperty(stickersGuid, "ARCHS", "armv7 arm64");
        pbxProject.SetBuildProperty(stickersGuid, "IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET", "10.0");
        pbxProject.SetBuildProperty(stickersGuid, "DEVELOPMENT_TEAM", "TEAMid");

        //Info.plist update
        string plistPath = buildPath + "/Stickers/Info.plist";
        PlistDocument plist = new PlistDocument();
        plist.ReadFromString(File.ReadAllText(plistPath));

        // Get root
        PlistElementDict rootDict = plist.root;

        rootDict.values["CFBundleVersion"] = new PlistElementString(PlayerSettings.iOS.buildNumber);
        rootDict.values["CFBundleShortVersionString"] = new PlistElementString(PlayerSettings.bundleVersion);

        // Write to info.plist file
        File.WriteAllText(plistPath, plist.WriteToString());

        // This is quite yuck, but there isn't a way with Unity's PBX library to add a scheme and we need to add one for the Stickers target or else xcodebuild fails when we try to build it
        File.WriteAllText(xcodeprojPath + "/xcshareddata/xcschemes/Stickers.xcscheme", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Scheme LastUpgradeVersion = \"0800\" wasCreatedForAppExtension = \"YES\" version = \"2.0\"><BuildAction parallelizeBuildables = \"YES\" buildImplicitDependencies = \"YES\"><BuildActionEntries><BuildActionEntry buildForTesting = \"YES\" buildForRunning = \"YES\" buildForProfiling = \"YES\" buildForArchiving = \"YES\" buildForAnalyzing = \"YES\"><BuildableReference BuildableIdentifier = \"primary\" BlueprintIdentifier = \"" + stickersGuid + "\" BuildableName = \"Stickers.appex\" BlueprintName = \"Stickers\" ReferencedContainer = \"container:Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj\"></BuildableReference></BuildActionEntry></BuildActionEntries></BuildAction><TestAction buildConfiguration = \"Debug\" selectedDebuggerIdentifier = \"Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.Debugger.LLDB\" selectedLauncherIdentifier = \"Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.Launcher.LLDB\" shouldUseLaunchSchemeArgsEnv = \"YES\"><Testables></Testables><MacroExpansion><BuildableReference BuildableIdentifier = \"primary\" BlueprintIdentifier = \"" + appGuid + "\" BuildableName = \"Unity-Target-New.app\" BlueprintName = \"Unity-iPhone\" ReferencedContainer = \"container:Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj\"></BuildableReference></MacroExpansion><AdditionalOptions></AdditionalOptions></TestAction><LaunchAction buildConfiguration = \"Debug\" selectedDebuggerIdentifier = \"\" selectedLauncherIdentifier = \"Xcode.IDEFoundation.Launcher.PosixSpawn\" launchStyle = \"0\" useCustomWorkingDirectory = \"NO\" ignoresPersistentStateOnLaunch = \"NO\" debugDocumentVersioning = \"YES\" debugServiceExtension = \"internal\" allowLocationSimulation = \"YES\" launchAutomaticallySubstyle = \"2\"><AdditionalOptions></AdditionalOptions></LaunchAction><ProfileAction buildConfiguration = \"Release\" shouldUseLaunchSchemeArgsEnv = \"YES\" savedToolIdentifier = \"\" useCustomWorkingDirectory = \"NO\" debugDocumentVersioning = \"YES\" launchAutomaticallySubstyle = \"2\"><MacroExpansion><BuildableReference BuildableIdentifier = \"primary\" BlueprintIdentifier = \"" + stickersGuid + "\" BuildableName = \"Stickers.appex\" BlueprintName = \"Stickers\" ReferencedContainer = \"container:Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj\"></BuildableReference></MacroExpansion></ProfileAction><AnalyzeAction buildConfiguration = \"Debug\"></AnalyzeAction><ArchiveAction buildConfiguration = \"Release\" revealArchiveInOrganizer = \"YES\"></ArchiveAction></Scheme>");
    }

    private static void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs, bool overrideDest = false)
    {
        // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);

        if (!dir.Exists)
        {
            throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("Source directory does not exist or could not be found: " + sourceDirName);
        }

        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
        // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it.
        if (!Directory.Exists (destDirName)) {
            Directory.CreateDirectory (destDirName);
        }
        else if(overrideDest)
        {
            Directory.Delete (destDirName, true);
            Directory.CreateDirectory (destDirName);
        }

        // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
            file.CopyTo(temppath, overrideDest);
        }

        // If copying subdirectories, copy them and their contents to new location.
        if (copySubDirs)
        {
            foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
            {
                string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
                DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs, overrideDest);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example besides the link?

Comment: Ah, and you have to put this script in an editor folder :)

Comment: And we have changed the namespace of the xcode api to MightyEditor

Comment: hi thanks，this seems promising，will try this and let you know

Comment: Hi, I am using Unity 2017.1 and seems there is not an `AddFileToResourcesForTarget` method of `PBXProject` what version are you using? and only found [addFileToBuild](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iOS.Xcode.PBXProject.AddFileToBuild.html) method there, are they the same?

Comment: I use 5.3.6, I think you should check AddFileToBuildSection and GetResourcesBuildPhaseByTarget  or create one with AddResourcesBuildPhase

Answer (score 0):

I'm on unity 2018.4...

Here's what I did to automate the stickers-embedding process into Unity post-process build.

- Copy the sticker assets into a folder, relative to unity project asset path
- For me the folder contains Stickers.xcassets and Info.plist. (Generated from XCode previously)
- Add this post process class into your project

```
//
// Copyright (c) 2020 Cizcuz (ID)
// http://www.twitter.com/cizcuz
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED,
// INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A
// PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT
// HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF
// CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE
// OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
//

using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Callbacks;
using UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode;
using UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode.Extensions;

public class PostProcess
{
    [PostProcessBuild(100)]
    public static void OnPostProcessBuild(BuildTarget target, string buildPath)
    {
        if (target == BuildTarget.iOS)
        {
            // Add the sticker extension to current pbx
            string PBXPath = PBXProject.GetPBXProjectPath(buildPath);
            PBXProject pbxProject = new PBXProject();
            pbxProject.ReadFromFile(PBXPath);            
            AddStickers(buildPath,pbxProject);
            pbxProject.WriteToFile(PBXPath);
            
            // After this, still need to fix app extension type 
            // I cant find any way to insert proper product Type from unity PBXProject class
            string output = File.ReadAllText(PBXPath);
            File.WriteAllText( PBXPath, output.Replace( "productType = \"com.apple.product-type.app-extension\"",
                                                        "productType = \"com.apple.product-type.app-extension.messages-sticker-pack\"" ) ); 
        }
    }
    
    private static void AddStickers(string buildPath, PBXProject pbxProject)
    {
        const string StickerPackRelPath = "";   // INSERT relative path from <path to project folder>/Assets to your Sticker Asset i.e.: "/../../StickerAssets"
        string stickerFolder = Path.GetFullPath( Application.dataPath + StickerPackRelPath );

        if( Directory.Exists(stickerFolder) ) {
            string PBXPath = PBXProject.GetPBXProjectPath(buildPath);
            string appGuid = pbxProject.TargetGuidByName(PBXProject.GetUnityTargetName());

            // Copy folder
            FileUtil.CopyFileOrDirectory(stickerFolder, buildPath + "/Stickers");

            //
            string stickersGuid = pbxProject.AddAppExtension(appGuid, "My Stickers", "com.yourcompany.yourgame.stickers", "Stickers/Info.plist");
            string stickerAssetGuid = pbxProject.AddFile("Stickers/Stickers.xcassets", "Stickers/Stickers.xcassets");
            pbxProject.AddFile("Stickers/Info.plist","Stickers/Info.plist");
            pbxProject.AddFileToBuild(stickersGuid, stickerAssetGuid);

            string debugConfig              = pbxProject.BuildConfigByName( stickersGuid, "Debug");
            string releaseConfig            = pbxProject.BuildConfigByName( stickersGuid, "Release");
            string releaseProfilingConfig   = pbxProject.BuildConfigByName( stickersGuid, "ReleaseForProfiling");
            string releaseRunningConfig     = pbxProject.BuildConfigByName( stickersGuid, "ReleaseForRunning");
            List<string> allRelease = new List<string>() {
                releaseConfig,
                releaseProfilingConfig,
                releaseRunningConfig
            };

            //
            // This is just to match build properties normally exist when you 
            // create the Sticker AppExtension Target by XCode, not really sure if all of this is essential
            // 
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER", "com.yourcompany.yourgame.stickers");
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY", "1,2");        // For me is iphone & ipad
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET", "10.2");   // Sticker project supported in iOS 10
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "COPY_PHASE_STRIP", "NO" ); 
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "DEVELOPMENT_TEAM", "");                 // INSERT #YOURTEAMID# HERE
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS", "NO");
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY", "iPhone Developer" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION", PlayerSettings.iOS.buildNumber );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "MARKETING_VERSION", PlayerSettings.bundleVersion );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD", "gnu11" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "GCC_WARN_64_TO_32_BIT_CONVERSION" ,"YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "GCC_WARN_ABOUT_RETURN_TYPE", "YES_ERROR" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "GCC_WARN_UNDECLARED_SELECTOR", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "GCC_WARN_UNINITIALIZED_AUTOS", "YES_AGGRESSIVE" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "GCC_WARN_UNUSED_FUNCTION", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD", "gnu++14" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY", "libc++" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_WEAK", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "ENABLE_STRICT_OBJC_MSGSEND", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_WARN_BLOCK_CAPTURE_AUTORELEASING", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_WARN_BOOL_CONVERSION", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_WARN_COMMA", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_WARN_CONSTANT_CONVERSION", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_WARN_DEPRECATED_OBJC_IMPLEMENTATIONS", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_WARN_DIRECT_OBJC_ISA_USAGE", "YES_ERROR" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_WARN_DOCUMENTATION_COMMENTS", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_WARN_EMPTY_BODY", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_WARN_ENUM_CONVERSION", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_WARN_INFINITE_RECURSION", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_WARN_INT_CONVERSION", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_WARN_NON_LITERAL_NULL_CONVERSION", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_WARN_OBJC_IMPLICIT_RETAIN_SELF", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_WARN_OBJC_LITERAL_CONVERSION", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_WARN_OBJC_ROOT_CLASS", "YES_ERROR" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_WARN_RANGE_LOOP_ANALYSIS", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_WARN_STRICT_PROTOTYPES", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_WARN_SUSPICIOUS_MOVE", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_WARN_UNGUARDED_AVAILABILITY", "YES_AGGRESSIVE" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_WARN_UNREACHABLE_CODE", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_WARN__DUPLICATE_METHOD_MATCH", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_ANALYZER_NONNULL", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "CLANG_ANALYZER_NUMBER_OBJECT_CONVERSION", "YES_AGGRESSIVE" );           
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty( stickersGuid, "MTL_FAST_MATH", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildPropertyForConfig( debugConfig, "ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildPropertyForConfig( debugConfig, "GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL", "0" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildPropertyForConfig( debugConfig, "DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT", "dwarf" ); 
            pbxProject.AddBuildPropertyForConfig( debugConfig, "ENABLE_TESTABILITY", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildPropertyForConfig( debugConfig, "MTL_ENABLE_DEBUG_INFO", "YES" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildPropertyForConfig( allRelease, "ENABLE_NS_ASSERTIONS", "NO" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildPropertyForConfig( allRelease, "MTL_ENABLE_DEBUG_INFO", "NO" );
            pbxProject.AddBuildPropertyForConfig( allRelease, "VALIDATE_PRODUCT", "YES" );

            // Sets property for asset catalog
            pbxProject.AddBuildProperty(stickersGuid, "ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME", "iMessage App Icon");

            //Info.plist update
            string plistPath = buildPath + "/Stickers/Info.plist";
            PlistDocument plist = new PlistDocument();
            plist.ReadFromString(File.ReadAllText(plistPath));

            // Get root
            PlistElementDict rootDict = plist.root;
            rootDict.values["CFBundleVersion"] = new PlistElementString(PlayerSettings.iOS.buildNumber);
            rootDict.values["CFBundleShortVersionString"] = new PlistElementString(PlayerSettings.bundleVersion);

            // Update info.plist file
            File.WriteAllText(plistPath, plist.WriteToString());
        }
    }
}
```